# Unnecessary updates on relationships auto-indexes

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

I am using Neo4j 1.9, and I have an auto-index configured on relationships for a property A.

```
(neo4j.properties)
relationship_auto_indexing=true
relationship_keys_indexable=A
```

When using a Gremlin script to set some properties other than A on an edge, the auto-index file is opened, read and written back. This slows down my queries a lot, and I don't see any reason for accessing the index for a property that is not indexed. Is this a normal behavior ?

I'm seeing the index file accesses with 'strace'.

Comment: What is the code you are running?

Comment: I'm sending a Gremlin script via REST (with neography).

Comment: Which auto-index file are you referring to?

Comment: The files under index/lucene/relationship/relationship_auto_index/ : _2tqq.nrm, _2tqq.cfs, _2tqq.tis etc